# What is the easy way to identify the soundtrack from any Hollywood movie?

Tags: soundtrack

I have a timeline where the music starts in a movie and have a sample audio of it.

For movies, IMDB and Wikipedia show different soundtracks, and some match while some others don't.

It is very difficult for me to search each and every song to match my sample. 
Is there any easy way to identify the tune?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What online resources are available for identifying songs from audio or score?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/what-online-resources-are-available-for-identifying-songs-from-audio-or-score)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

There is no **easy** way to be sure to identify 100% of any Hollywood movie soundtrack.

IMDB and Wikipedia are essentially made by fans, regular internet users who may fill the articles with incomplete or mistaken information. So mismatches can happen, and these sources can sometimes be uncertain.

**The most reliable source is the ending credits from the movie itself.** It will end with a large list of all songs that featured in the movie, *but* this list is sometimes incomplete (check this [question from Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60015/why-arent-the-songs-from-a-tv-show-credited-in-the-end-credits)).

Sometimes, the song can also be uncredited, because it comes from a music library. The movie company buys a large number of songs and the song's name, artists are uncredited in the process (check this question [How can I find the soundtrack list for documentaries?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4774/how-can-i-find-the-soundtrack-list-for-documentaries/4775#4775)).

---

Mel Padden suggested Shazam, and you can also try SoundHound. Ultimately, you can ask the question on this community, with the respect of the [rules](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) and after [optmizing your question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Shazam? I often find that if you catch the movie's soundtrack just as it swells above the dialogue, that works quite well.