# the piano background of this video

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, piano

I am not intending to promote any video or political information. However, when I was listening to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sj2Hio4Adw), the background music amazed me.

What is the background music of this video? It is more clear from [1:44](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sj2Hio4Adw#t=104) (on headphone/headset but not laptop speaker).
This is my question for many of other musics as well. If there is any tool for searching the background music online, please let me know.

Comment: I really don't want to ruin your hopes, but it seems to be a random music library so almost impossible to track down. The best way to know it is contacting the video producer. Now if you want to know how to identify soundtracks in general, a similar topic has been discussed [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/what-is-the-easy-way-to-identify-the-soundtrack-from-any-hollywood-movie).

Comment: @Bebs, Many thanks. The producer has not answered to this question. Would you please identify the genre and style of this music so one can search for similar ones?

Comment: In this case you should edit or rewrite your questions for people to understand... don't ask questions in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The name of this song is

> At The Bea (S) T Of The Drums

Genre: Synth Pop

By: My terminal and the trip & Gehard Graf

[Listen preview](https://www.music-bazaar.com/world-music/album/1279501/Prayers-From-Hell/)

Comment: It's amazing you were able to find this! How did you locate it?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like a piano to. It's probably a hang drum. 
Could be these guys: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xk3BvNLeNgw / http://facebook.com/hangmassive / http://hangmusic.com

Comment: Maybe not piano. But, to my ear it is hard to consider it as a hang too. Is it a computer modified hang?